# Detecting a left button mouse click Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

What I'm trying to do is get my winform to display a debug line when ever I click in my winform. However, when I do, nothing happens. I know how to get a button / other click event to happen. But what I need is to be able to click anywhere within my winform.

I've googled this for the past hour but can't see what I'm doing wrong. As far as I'm aware, this code should be correct in detecting a mouse click. This method is held withing the form1.cs class:

```
private void mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        Trace.WriteLine("Mouse clicked");
}
```

I've tried setting brake points, but these don't get triggered either. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for the stupidly newbie question, but I am very new to winform programming.

Comment: Something has to trigger the `mouseClick()` method. Did you set the `OnClick` event of your form?

Comment: You show the method you want to invoke when a mouse-click occurs, but have you actually added an event handler that calls this method?

Comment: Damn. No I haven't. How do I do that?

Comment: Just do a double click on form and it will create mouse click handler for you,

Comment: @Hafeez, double-clicking on a form creates a Form_Load handler for you, not a mouse click handler.

Comment: I made a stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How to add the EventHandler:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // This line should you place in the InitializeComponent() method.
    this.MouseClick += mouseClick;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the editor built-in to Visual Studio:

[image]

1. Go to the properties window (if you don't see it, press `Alt + Enter`).
2. Select the events icon (looks like lightning).
3. Double-click on the empty ComboBox to the right of **Click**.
4. You'll be taken to an empty method where you can put your code.

Answer (score 4):

The method itself is correct. I think your actual problem is: you haven't added this method to `MouseClick` events.

In C# – and most other languages too – event is handled by an event handler. Windows forms and controls have events for all the events happening in your controls, such as `OnClick` or `OnResize`.
You can append methods to these events, and the methods will automatically get called when the  actual event happens. Simply add the following line to your form's constructor, `Form_Load`-method, `InitializeComponent`-method, or such:

```
this.MouseClick += mouseClick;
```

Now when ever `MouseClick` event happens, your method `mouseClick` will be called automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend reading   [Events C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/awbftdfh.aspx). You need to add an event handler like so:

```
form1.MouseClick += mouseClick;
```