# Player to move to last click at a certain speed, C#

Tags: c#

I am looking to get the player to move to the cursor's last clicked location at a slow rate.  I have attempted this and only achieved it as a constant (the player is constantly following the cursor). I do not wish for this to happen and I only want it to work when clicking within the window.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
    private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
            tmrMoving.Enabled = true;
            Invalidate();
     }

    private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           player.Location = (Cursor.Position);
           Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions/methods?

**Edit**
I have edited your code Henrik but now I have a double => int problem any resolve?

```
private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var xdiff = Cursor.Position.X - player.Location.X;
            var ydiff = Cursor.Position.Y - player.Location.Y; 
            var diff = Math.Sqrt(xdiff + ydiff);

           // xdiff = player.Location.X;
           // ydiff = player.Location.Y;
    }
```

Comment: You need to detect when the [mouse was clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645233/detecting-a-left-button-mouse-click-winform) instead of if the mouse button is down or not

Comment: I find your question little cryptic, player??

Comment: player = picturebox

I did attempt the click but the "player" still jumps to the position not moves towards the position; I am unsure on how to increment the movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
player.Location = (Cursor.Position);
```

by something like this

```
var diff = Cursor.Position - new System.Windows.Point(player.Location.X,player.Location.Y);
var speed = Math.Sqrt( diff.X * diff.X + diff.Y * diff.Y);
if (speed > 10)
{
    diff.X /= speed / 10;
    diff.Y /= speed / 10;
}
player.Location += new System.Drawing.Point( (int)diff.X, (int)diff.Y);
```

Comment: Can't quite do that because you can't use mathematical operands on the Cursor's Position.

Comment: @AshleyFayers did you try?

Comment: Yes, `var diff = Cursor.Position - player.Location;` will not function as the `Cursor.Position` cannot accept that operand.

Comment: @AshleyFayers Yes, I see your problem now. `Cursor.Position` is `System.Windows.Point`, but `PictureBox.Location` is `System.Drawing.Point`. Very confusing. See my edit. I hope it helps. I didn't compile it, but at least you should get the idea.

Comment: So close!! 
**Error** 1 The type or namespace name 'Point' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) This is the only error. **Thanks though, I understand this so much more now.**

Comment: @AshleyFayers Try adding a reference to `WindowsBase` to your project.

Comment: That has brought up the previous error, (-) operand cannot be used with windows.point and drawing.point...

Comment: `~~var playerPoint = new System.Windows.Point(player.Location.X, player.Location.Y);  
~~var diff = Cursor.Position - playerPoint;`

@Henrik This didn't even work, it refuses to let me convert player.Location to a _Windows.Point_ it constantly reminds me I can't put a _Windows.Point_ with a _Drawing.Point_  very frustrating stuff right here.

Comment: **Even when I hover over the lines of code it tells me they are both System.Windows.Point functions?** Not sure what to do, this may be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

What I don't see here is when the timer stops processing.
The basic steps, in my mind, might look like this:

- You handle [MouseDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx) event
- Save a position of mouse when it was clicked in private `Queue<T>` and start timer
- In timer handler, get the first point entered inside the 'Queue' and save it inside some field (`curPointToProcess` ??).
- Move your object toward the point on every tick. The speed is controled or by frequency of tick or by amount object moved per tick, or by both.
- Once object reached the point, check if there is another point inside the `Queue<T>`

  - yes: get the point and proceed with last 2 steps again
  - no: stop the timer and wait for another `MouseDown`

You have to have some kind of `Queue<T>` cause while you are moving the object toward the point, user might furiously click on other points, you need to save them and process one after another in sequence, unless your design expects something else.

Comment: Similar but I don't want to save the last location the next one overwrites the previous one.

Comment: I don't know how your moving algorithms works, but if you need only single destination overall, you can avoid having a collection of points. If the behavior of object changes depends on direction, so may be algorithm, you may still need a notion of a fact that point *was changed*.

Comment: Basically a fast moving maze game, every click the player moves towards a _safe zone_ and cannot be _hurt_ (by the environment) when stood on this _safe zone_. The player will click to move and be in constant move until they reach the destination or click to move to another location.

Comment: So you may have only a single point, as you said, and on every "step" inside a timer get the "current point" and move along the vector pointing to it.

Comment: Okay so I understand how to do most of that, variables representing values and whatnot but how do I  perform the steps and the moving? I could move the object but not in steps/slowly?

Comment: There are a lot different ways, if you want to use a vector line, you may look on @Henrik's answer and get a starting point from it.

Comment: any idea on how to correct Henrik's answer? It's just that one line?

Comment: At first glance, it should work for you. May be with some small adjustments to fit your needs.

Comment: I have adjusted it with my naming conventions but it refuses to accept the (-) operand.

Comment: Just create a new point (Location.x - player.location.x)(Location.y - player.location.y)

Comment: How does that work? What can use to represent my first location?? I can't just put _Location_....

Comment: Cursor.Position is a `Point`, right? Your object has to have its current Location, which should the `Point` either, right? So make the difference between the mouse position and *current* object position and move the object with some step toward the position clicked by mouse.

Comment: Yeah but the cursor's position can't be returned as value for re-import and the cursor.position statement cannot accept the - operand; it will not accept it.

Comment: Search on internet how to get difference between Mouse position point and some other point (your object's point). There are plenty of examples of how achieve that, that may help you...